# Will I miss out if I don't take the top tier skills?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

So my Guardian is 45 now, and I'm rapidly running out of points to put into skills. I'm using the defence tree, and I don't think I'll have enough points to get to Guardian Strike.

Will I be missing out by not taking the top tier skills? Should I be working up to these in my build? I was forced to respec in the 1.2 update, so tried Vigilance (dmg) and didn't enjoy it.

So will not having the top tier skills matter in the end-game content?

Comment: Shouldn't you already have top tier? At level 40 you can get top tier talents already, and you should. Most builds only stick 31 points in one and then put the rest where they are the most usefull. Sticking a few points in another tree isn't going to change your play tho...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the Discipline system introduced in Patch 3.0 means that you cannot avoid taking skills for a spec -- they're all selected for you and limited to one tree.  As such, this is no longer an issue.

Comment: Voting to leave open as per [What should be done with out of version questions?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/5727/4797) and [What do we do with historic questions that no longer make sense?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7235/4797)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it will matter.

Since you're talking about end-game content, by being a Guardian you're supposed to be a tank, and that means taunting your enemies, surviving, and helping your group in their damage dealing.

[Guardian slash](http://www.torhead.com/ability/ei80ttO/guardian-slash) accomplishes two of those three tasks, being a huge taunt and a stacking armor reduction that changes into bonus damage when it's full stacked.

If you're struggling with talent points placement I suggest you to search for talent builds around the web(simply looking for "swtor talent builds" can bring a lot of useful results).

By the way, it seems that the Vigilance spec is better for tanking purposes (I cannot say that by experience, since I've never palyed a Knight). If instead you're not trying to be a tank, I suggest you to try the Focus spec.

**EDIT:** since you're a solo player, as you said in the comments, then no, it won't make that much difference, except for the fact that you'll be killing thins at a slower pace(and you'll be missing the armor reduction part that might come handy with the tougher opponents)
Playing alone you won't need the threat component of the spell, since your opponent would already be focused on you.
Keep in mind anyway that, should you be grouping for a flashpoint or an operation, you'd be doing your group a disservice going in without the proper points distribution.

Comment: I think you're right, however my play style is unique in that I only play by myself, only ever do PvE and don't really ever group with anyone. Just for reference, my own build is this one, http://www.torhead.com/skill-calc#500GMGzudMdzZfRMzMZ0M.1

Comment: @DavidYell Edited the answer to reflect the informations you gave me

Comment: It's a shame that the game is so limited in this way that I can't do content because I've configured my character how I want.

Comment: Plus I think Guardian slash specifically has been updated, as I'm certain it used to be 'leap to target ally'

Comment: @DavidYell not really. You play however you want, but obviously there are builds that are better than others for specific things.  You can tank without it, you just won't be the 'best' tank you could be (but on the other hand, your build may be better for when you're soloing), but don't let that take from your enjoyment of the game.